# How to run a Box-Tidwell test in R to test for a linear relationship between the independent variables and log odds?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am using logistic regression to predict the presence/absence of red-cockaded woodpeckers. I have five continuous independent variables: AGE (mean age of forest stand), CANCOV (percent canopy cover), GROCOV (percent ground cover), AREA (size of stand in hectares), and BASAR (basal area). I also have one categorical variable: BURN (0=not burned, 1=burned annually, 2=burned every other year). How would I run a Box-Tidwell test for this data in R?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boxTidwell` function from `car` package.

In this public example, income and education variables are tested for non-linear relationship to the mean prestige adjusting for type and squared women variables. Income variables is significant.

```
library(car)

data(Prestige)
boxTidwell(prestige ~ income + education, ~ type + poly(women, 2), data = Prestige)

##           Score Statistic   p-value MLE of lambda
## income          -4.482406 0.0000074    -0.3476283
## education        0.216991 0.8282154     1.2538274
## 
## iterations =  8
```

Comment: Thank you for your response...I had already identified the boxTidwell function in the car package, but I am having trouble figuring out how to enter my data correctly into the code. I am brand new to R, and struggling with adapting codes to my specific needs without producing an error code.

Comment: The problem is: giving advice without testing is cumbersome. I at least need the head of you your data to see and test the structure: `head(mydata)`. Then I need to now which variables do you want to test and for which of them do you want to adjust. Why do you intend to test for non-linear relationsship? etc.. etc...